# Ultisnips capital and lower character in same snippet

Tags: plugin-ultisnips, snippets

I am trying to expand my snippets. I use `Ultisnips`.

ofcourse, I can have

```
snippet 'a "greek alpha" A
\alpha
endsnippet
```

and

```
snippet 'A "greek alpha" A
\Alpha
endsnippet
```

and both works fine.
But, I am looking for something like

```
snippet '[aA] "greek alpha" A
\[aA]lpha
endsnippet
```

i.e. if I put `'a`, I will get `\alpha`, with `'A`, I will get `\Alpha` from same snippet.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible to use parts of the snippet trigger in the output, but it's not as simple as using a matching character class on each side.

To correctly configure this, you need to use an `r` flag to use a regular expression in the trigger, use a capturing group inside parens for the character class (the trigger needs to be inside quotes as well.)

And then in the expansion you need to use a Python block and access the `match` object to get the contents of the capture group.

This snippet does it:

```
snippet "'([aA])" "greek alpha" rA
\\`!p snip.rv = match.group(1)`lpha
endsnippet
```

Comment: Ah! Much ado about a little thing. I will skip that.